# repositioning of y-label in R

Tags: r, plot, label

So taking the following dataset for example

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
```

Now using the `mgp` we can rescale the axis title, axis labels and axis line. Help can be found in `?par()`
I wish to move the position of the y label closer to the vertical label and keep the x at the default value of 3.
How can one do such?

Something along the lines of `mgp = c((1.5,3),1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The following would do it, you need to play around with the three parameters:

```
par(mgp=c(axis.title.position=2, axis.label.position=1, axis.line.position=0))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `mtext` to add the labels after plotting. So something like:

```
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg", xlab="", ylab="")
mtext("X", side=1, padj=2)
mtext("Y", side=2, padj=-3)
```